# Mysql Transaction using InnoDB engine doesn't work

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, innodb

the first and second insertion should be canceled (casue the second based on the first). anyway the transaction here doesn't work it commits the first one even if the second goes error,
for `SET autocommit = 0` tried using `= off` and both inside the transaction and outside it.

```
SET autocommit = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
insert into rooms
values
("test","0000","0000");
insert into assign_write_rooms
values
("0000","notest","0000");
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Can you tell us how you got query 2 to error? And what the error was.

Comment: change **COMMIT** to **ROLLBACK** to see if it works. it can be that the problem is in the workbench. It only works if the workbench use one connection for all querys

Comment: @P.Salmon  Error code: 1452 (foreign key constraint)

Comment: @BerndBuffen y i've tried `ROLLBACK` it doesn't save anything even for first insertion

Answer (score 1):

i think this is not an error.

I have startet 2 MySQL clients. In the left half I started the transaction with 2 inserts. the second with a error. In the right client i cant never see the data. When i close the connection the data is rollback

```
mysql> select * from rollb;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
                                                mysql> select * from rollb;
                                                Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set autocommit=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into rollb VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
                                                mysql> select * from rollb;
                                                Empty set (0.00 sec)


mysql> insert into rollb VALUES (1);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
mysql> select * from rollb;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
                                                mysql> select * from rollb;
                                                Empty set (0.00 sec)


mysql>
```